# Can Xbee run code without being connected to another device?

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this. Sorry if I'm wrong.

I'd like to know if you can run code in an Xbee module without being connected to the computer or another device like arduino.

For example, I want to have 2-3 Xbee modules that communicate with each other sending information and then take decisions by code dynamically without using the X-CTU software. And I don't want those Xbee modules to be connected to the PC or other devices, they have to run by themselves with a coin cell battery and run some code previously written into their memory. Is this possible? If so, can you provide me some info/documentation to take a look? which language do you have to use to program the code? Which Xbee model do I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XBEE modules can not do such tasks without a host. You can not run your own code on the module.

If you want to run you own code on the same device as the ZigBee stack then you should choose a solution from a silicon/stack provider.

You could achieve your goal using the Texas Instruments ZigBee Home automation SDK from www.ti.com/tool/z-stack which runs the ZigBee stack and your application on one of the TI ZigBee SoC's. But there are likely other similar providers as well.

Regards, TC.

Answer (score 0):

XBees can be configured to initialize themselves with network data, i.e. the PAN ID, so they're aware of how to communicate on start up without requiring external configuration. However, they cannot run headlessly; they must to have some idea of the data that needs to be sent. They're fundamentally designed to act as a transparent serial bridge between computers to aid communications on personal networks. They cannot however be configured to do something bespoke.

It sounds like you're worried about power, so you could try looking for a low-power microcontroller that possesses a USART; this is all you'll need in order to communicate with an XBee via Serial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not about the power. I want them to run code without the need of any external device. For example, write some code that is listening a channel and if it detects X condition in that channel then switch to another one and send to other Xbee module a message.

Comment: Okay, in that case I don't believe this is possible. You need to have some device which is in charge of what the is transmitted and when, and able to make sense of the application-specific data contained in the packets.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to put your own code on a standard XBee module, but Digi does offer a [Programmable XBee](http://www.digi.com/support/productdetail?pid=4624&osvid=0&type=documentation) that includes a Freescale HCS08 co-processor that you can write code for.  They offer a development kit with sample programs to get your started.

For a small-scale project where you don't need to be ZigBee certified, that might be easier than getting up to speed with a ZigBee development kit from TI, Freescale or Silicon Labs.